# Entity Type Does Not Declare Navigation Type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

I've Googled this error, and tried a number of different solutions and nothing worked. When I try using Eager Loading to get related entities for a specific entity I receive the following error:

```
A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'Link' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'Like'.
```

I have tried a number of different solutions in my OnModelCreating method in the DBContext, but kept receiving the same error. I finally just created another project and used the Entity Framework Power Tools to auto-generate everything for me (in case I was just doing something incorrectly by hand), but still get the error.

Any help in pointing me in the right direction to resolving this is greatly appreciated. I've been stuck on it for a while and it's preventing me from moving forward.

**Here's how I'm trying to use Eager Loading:**

```
using(var context = new LPContext())
{
    var links = context.ViewLinks.Include("Link.Like").ToList();
}
```

**Here are my entities:**

```
public partial class ViewLink
{
    public string OverrideLinkName { get; set; }

    public string OverrideDescription { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public int ViewLinkID { get; set; }

    public Nullable<int> ViewID { get; set; }

    public Nullable<int> LinkID { get; set; }

    public Nullable<int> CreatedByID { get; set; }

    public virtual Link Link { get; set; }
}

public partial class Link
{
    public Link()
    {
        this.Likes = new List<Like>();
        this.Visits = new List<Visit>();
    }

    public string LinkName { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string WebsiteURL { get; set; }

    public string ImageData { get; set; }

    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedOn { get; set; }

    public Nullable<System.DateTime> LastModified { get; set; }

    public int LinkID { get; set; }

    public Nullable<int> CreatedByID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Like> Likes { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ViewLink> ViewLinks { get; set; }
}

public partial class Like
{
    public string LikedBy { get; set; }

    public Nullable<System.DateTime> LikedOn { get; set; }

    public int LikeID { get; set; }

    public Nullable<int> LinkID { get; set; }

    public Nullable<int> LikedByID { get; set; }

    public virtual Link Link { get; set; }
}
```

**Here are my mapping files for those entities:**

```
public class LinkMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Link>
{
    public LinkMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.LinkID);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.LinkName)
            .HasMaxLength(150);

        this.Property(t => t.Description)
            .HasMaxLength(255);

        this.Property(t => t.WebsiteURL)
            .HasMaxLength(255);

        this.Property(t => t.CreatedBy)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("tblExplorerLinks");
        this.Property(t => t.LinkName).HasColumnName("LinkName");
        this.Property(t => t.Description).HasColumnName("Description");
        this.Property(t => t.WebsiteURL).HasColumnName("WebsiteURL");
        this.Property(t => t.ImageData).HasColumnName("ImageData");
        this.Property(t => t.CreatedBy).HasColumnName("CreatedBy");
        this.Property(t => t.CreatedOn).HasColumnName("CreatedOn");
        this.Property(t => t.LastModified).HasColumnName("LastModified");
        this.Property(t => t.LinkID).HasColumnName("LinkID");
        this.Property(t => t.CreatedByID).HasColumnName("CreatedByID");
    }
}

public class LikeMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Like>
{
    public LikeMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.LikeID);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.LikedBy)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("tblExplorerLikes");
        this.Property(t => t.LikedBy).HasColumnName("LikedBy");
        this.Property(t => t.LikedOn).HasColumnName("LikedOn");
        this.Property(t => t.LikeID).HasColumnName("LikeID");
        this.Property(t => t.LinkID).HasColumnName("LinkID");
        this.Property(t => t.LikedByID).HasColumnName("LikedByID");

        // Relationships
        this.HasOptional(t => t.Link)
            .WithMany(t => t.Likes)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.LinkID);
    }
}
```

**And finally here is my OnModelCreating() method**

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new LikeMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new LinkMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ViewLinkMap());
    }
```

If there is anything else that I can provide I will do so. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is correct.

`Link` doesn't have a `Like` property, it has a `Likes` property. A `Link` can have many `Likes`. If you want to load all of a `Link`'s `Likes`, just fix up your include string:

```
using(var context = new LPContext())
{
    var links = context.ViewLinks.Include("Link.Likes").ToList();
}
```

Comment: And..I feel incredibly stupid right now. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Oh, no worries. It's hard to spot. In EF 5.0 and up you can get away from the hard-coded strings and use a lambda expression (e.g. `context.ViewLinks.Include(vl => vl.Link.Likes).ToList()`).

Comment: Unfortunately I have to use the hard coded strings. My company has a custom framework that I have to use that I pass the eager loading string to. The examples above don't look like the exact code I'm going to use in production, but it is the same concept and was producing the same error. It's just nobody here is going to have an answer to a company's unique framework, ya know? Thanks again.

Comment: Oh yes, I know :) As simple as the answer was, don't forget to accept it if it solved your problem. OTOH, I'm going to vote to close due to a simple typographical error.